# Java 11 GC logging

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have one app running with java 11 with gc logging enabled.
I see following lines printed in GC log every 5/6 second. does it mean GC is running every 5 seconds ?

```
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.789-0400][gc,start      ] GC(353) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.789-0400][gc,task       ] GC(353) Using 8 workers of 8 for evacuation
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,phases     ] GC(353)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.0ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,phases     ] GC(353)   Evacuate Collection Set: 0.6ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,phases     ] GC(353)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.5ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,phases     ] GC(353)   Other: 0.3ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(353) Eden regions: 147->0(147)
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(353) Survivor regions: 1->1(19)
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(353) Old regions: 16->16
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(353) Humongous regions: 1->1
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,metaspace  ] GC(353) Metaspace: 43129K->43129K(1089536K)
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.791-0400][gc            ] GC(353) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 163M->16M(248M) 1.689ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.791-0400][gc,cpu        ] GC(353) User=0.00s Sys=0.01s Real=0.01s
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.411-0400][gc,start      ] GC(354) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.411-0400][gc,task       ] GC(354) Using 8 workers of 8 for evacuation
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.412-0400][gc,phases     ] GC(354)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.0ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.412-0400][gc,phases     ] GC(354)   Evacuate Collection Set: 0.6ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.412-0400][gc,phases     ] GC(354)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.5ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.412-0400][gc,phases     ] GC(354)   Other: 0.3ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.412-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(354) Eden regions: 147->0(147)
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.412-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(354) Survivor regions: 1->1(19)
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.412-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(354) Old regions: 16->16
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.412-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(354) Humongous regions: 1->1
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.412-0400][gc,metaspace  ] GC(354) Metaspace: 43129K->43129K(1089536K)
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.412-0400][gc            ] GC(354) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 163M->16M(248M) 1.536ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:20.412-0400][gc,cpu        ] GC(354) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.939-0400][gc,start      ] GC(355) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause)
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.939-0400][gc,task       ] GC(355) Using 8 workers of 8 for evacuation
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.940-0400][gc,phases     ] GC(355)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.0ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.940-0400][gc,phases     ] GC(355)   Evacuate Collection Set: 0.6ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.940-0400][gc,phases     ] GC(355)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.5ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.940-0400][gc,phases     ] GC(355)   Other: 0.3ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.940-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(355) Eden regions: 147->0(147)
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.940-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(355) Survivor regions: 1->1(19)
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.940-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(355) Old regions: 16->16
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.940-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(355) Humongous regions: 1->1
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.940-0400][gc,metaspace  ] GC(355) Metaspace: 43129K->43129K(1089536K)
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.940-0400][gc            ] GC(355) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 163M->16M(248M) 1.537ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:25.940-0400][gc,cpu        ] GC(355) User=0.01s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s
```

Comment: Yes. And since this is Java 11, default GC is G1 GC. It is not a stop the world GC and does it only on small regions of the heap.

Comment: @Nishit G1 is Stop The World GC

Comment: @AlexeyRagozin My apologies. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does. It also means your application is stopped for about `1.5 ms` for GC work. Specifically it cleans young generation regions. This is normal, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Does it mean GC get triggered every 5/6 seconds irrespective of the memory usage by app ?

Comment: @dsingh what do you mean irrespective? Your young regions are getting full, thus the GC is triggered

Comment: I have increased the heap size from 256MB to 512MB using -Xmx512m
observed the log file for several minutes. i see the log lines printed in the log exactly every 5 or 6 minutes. its very unlikely that memory regions getting full exactly every 5 or 6 minutes.
Sorry i am from C++ background and recently started managing a java app. not have much idea about java GC.

Comment: If GC is triggered, that means your application allocates stuff and regions _are_ getting full, this has nothing to do with likehood; it is a fact proven by existence of such entries in logs. And `-Xmx` increases the maximum memory, FYI. To re-iterate this is how a GC works in the JVM world - this _is_ normal.