# Understanding GC1 log file in java 11

Tags: garbage-collection, java-11

As part of the question in [Java 11 GC logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62897054/java-11-gc-logging) I am struggling to understand what the numbers actually mean.

For example:

```
  [2020-07-14T10:01:14.791-0400][gc            ] GC(353) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 163M->16M(248M) 1.689ms
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(353) Eden regions: 147->0(147)
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(353) Survivor regions: 1->1(19)
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(353) Old regions: 16->16
[2020-07-14T10:01:14.790-0400][gc,heap       ] GC(353) Humongous regions: 1->1
```

I know that `147->0` is before/after collection, but what is the unit here and for the ones below? As I see it, is that the whole young generation is reduced from 163M to 16M , it also looks like this happens almost entirely within the Eden regions - so the objects already went out of scope before even moving to the survivor space?

Comment: The units seem to match the units of the summary entry, i.e. `163M->16M`, which has the same difference as `147->0`. So this might imply that 147M have been collected entirely from the Eden space. But it could also mean that some objects have been moved from Eden to Survivor space while objects with the same total amount of memory have been collected from the Survivor space in the same cycle.

Comment: Is there a chance that within the same cyycle the memory goes to survivor space and then gets collected. That sounds to be less efficient. Any reference to how this could potentially  be optimised, if I know that most objects only live in the eden space?

Comment: After a young collection `Eden` and one of the survivors, `Survivor-from`, are always completely erased.

Comment: @A2LBK no, I was talking about the scenario that an amount of objects gets copied to the survivor space while the same amount of *different* objects gets collected from the survivor space in the same cycle, which you wouldn’t notice by looking at this number. This doesn’t mean that there’s anything to optimize. You’re looking at the wrong numbers. Look at the application’s CPU consumption and its fraction spent in garbage collection. How much is it? If it is, e.g. 1%, it means regardless of how hard you try, you will never gain more than 1% CPU performance out of optimizing garbage collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the unit here

[A region](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/gctuning/garbage-first-garbage-collector.htm#JSGCT-GUID-15921907-B297-43A4-8C48-DC88035BC7CF). Region size varies based on heap size or an explicit setting.

> it also looks like this happens almost entirely within the Eden regions - so the objects already went out of scope before even moving to the survivor space?

Most of them, a small amount might still trickle into later generations but on the other hand those regions may also contain now-dead objects that can be collected so it's mostly in equilibrium with only a very small flow towards the old generation. This kind of behavior is what makes generational collectors so efficient.